# Biblatex: redefine doi to display the full URL

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, doi

I use the authoryear style for Biblatex. For articles that have a DOI, biblatex+biber automatically produce the following in the bibliography:

> DOI : 10.1162/qjec.2008.123.1.49

which contains a hyperref link to :  https://doi.org/10.1162/qjec.2008.123.1.49

I would like to know how to change the style so that the DOI would also display the full link, that is, that it would display:

> DOI : https://doi.org/10.1162/qjec.2008.123.1.49

and still link to the same URL https://doi.org/10.1162/qjec.2008.123.1.49

Thank you!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[%url=false,eprint=false,
 style=authoryear,  backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{GabaixLandier_2008,
    author               = {Gabaix, Xavier and Landier, Augustin},
    doi                  = {10.1162/qjec.2008.123.1.49},
    journal              = {The Quarterly Journal of Economics},
    number               = {1},
    pages                = {49-100},
    title                = {Why has CEO Pay Increased So Much?},
    volume               = {123},
    year                 = {2008},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Dummytext~\autocite{GabaixLandier_2008}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: A [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) would be nice!

Comment: I've edited my answer to include it, also there is a working answer!

Comment: Thanks for the MWE! Even if the experts where too fast in answering :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble after loading `biblatex`:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{https://doi.org/#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{https://doi.org/#1}}}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space\url{https://doi.org/#1}}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer this over mine? Just curious.

Comment: @AlanMunn It looks nicer, I think. (Plus, it actually works ;-))

Comment: Yeah, I fixed the working part.  But I don't see the aesthetic difference.

Comment: @AlanMunn I prefer my solution because I don't have to go into an `\if...` branch that essentially does the same for both cases.